# Implementing interface member with arguments that are more derived than in those in the interface declaration?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, theory

Is there a way to implement this so that I can use overloaded methods with more derived arguments? The overloaded methods aren't matching the signature as defined in the interface, even though they inherit from the `Command` class, but they should still be interchangeable, right?

```
public class Command {}

public interface IHandler
{
    public Result Handle(Command cmd);
}

public class CommandOne : Command {}
public class CommandTwo : Command {}

public class HandlerA: IHandler
{
    public Result Handle(CommandOne cmd) {...}
    public Result Handle(CommandTwo cmd) {...}
}
```

I suppose this is not allowed since it would allow you to do this which doesn't make sense:

```
public class CommandThree : Command {}

public class HandlerB: IHandler
{
    public Result Handle(CommandOne cmd) {...}
    public Result Handle(CommandThree cmd) {...}
}

IHandler handler = new HandlerA();

handler.Handle(new CommandThree()); // this is not defined
```

But is there a way to get around this like implementing a default method that would get called if there is no matching signature? Like so:

```
public class HandlerC: IHandler
{
    public Result Handle(CommandOne cmd) {...}
    public Result Handle(CommandTwo cmd) {...}

    public Result Handle(Command cmd) {...}
}
```

This compiles but will lead to a `NotImplementedException` when I try to call the Handle method with any derived class. I'm assuming this is because the interface only has that one method with the signature using the `Command` class.

```
IHandler handler = new HandlerC();
handler.Handle(new Command()); // works
handler.Handle(new CommandOne()); //NotImplementedException
```

Is there even a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must implement the interface as it is declared, so you must declare a method with a parameter of the base class type. You can overload the method with parameters of more specific types though. Only the interface method can be called via a reference of the interface type, but you can implement that method such that it calls the other overloads if the argument is the appropriate type, e.g.

```cs
public class HandlerD : IHandler
{
    public Result Handle(CommandOne cmd) { /* ... */ }
    public Result Handle(CommandTwo cmd) { /* ... */ }

    public Result Handle(Command cmd)
    {
        if (cmd is CommandOne cmd1)
        {
            return Handle(cmd1);
        }

        if (cmd is CommandTwo cmd2)
        {
            return Handle(cmd2);
        }

        // Default implementation here.
    }
}
```